# On SQL Server, how to find the MAX or MIN value out of a couple of variables

Tags: sql-server, max

I just found out that the MAX() function in SQL only works on columns.

Is there a similar function I can use to find the max value out of e.g. these four variables?

```
SET @return = MAX(@alpha1, @alpha2, @alpha3, @alpha4)
```

Or do I have to put them in a column first (and thus create a table first...;-(    )?

Regards

Lumpi

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in function in T-SQL for this but you can use following

```
SELECT @result = MAX(alpha)
FROM   (SELECT @alpha1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT @alpha2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT @alpha3) T(alpha);
```

or (SQL Server 2008+)

```
SELECT @result = MAX(alpha)
FROM  (VALUES(@alpha1),
             (@alpha2),
             (@alpha3)) T(alpha);
```

Comment: Thank you! Why does alternative 1 not work on earlyer SQl server versions?

Comment: @Lumpi - Alternative 2 I think you mean? Row Value Construcvtors were not introduced until that version.

Comment: I really miss `least()` and `greatest()` function from Postgress - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html. It's so much easier to read and use them...